# Unable to execute ipython notebook command successfully on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda python distribution. However, after executing "ipython notebook" I am not able to execute it successfully and system yields the following error. I am clueless, what has went wrong ?

Thanks.

```
AbhayBhadani-MacBook:~ abhaybhadani$ ipython --version

3.0.0

AbhayBhadani-MacBook:~ abhaybhadani$ which ipython

/opt/anaconda/bin/ipython

AbhayBhadani-MacBook:~ abhaybhadani$ ipython notebook

[I 11:25:33.829 NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/Users/abhaybhadani/.ipython/profile_default'

[I 11:25:33.833 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/anaconda/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)

  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)

  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)

  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)

  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 409, in initialize_subcommand
    self.subapp.initialize(argv)

  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 980, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 842, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 125, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 145, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)

  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address


If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org


You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.


Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

Comment: Have you tried this: "If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org" ?

Comment: Anaconda doesn't install all notebook dependencies by default, IIRC: try  `conda install ipython-notebook`  to make sure.

Comment: Thanks Ian , I has installed conda update ipython ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole. But, this error appeared  after installing whole package.

Comment: I was able to solve this by simply typing:  ipython notebook --ip=127.0.0.1 at the terminal :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is just building on the answer that @Abhay Bhadani already provided for himself, since I can't seem to find the root cause myself**

You may try to edit your ipython profile. In my case I had to create a profile with the following command:

```
ipython profile create
```

then append the following line to the ipython notebook config. In my case that file is located at `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py` which is the default location for profiles that are created without a name. Once found, append the following config option:

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '127.0.0.1'
```

then, when running `ipython notebook`, it will open as usual without the need to provide the ip argument. So not much of an improvement from your solution, but I prefer it that way :)

In the case that you're really interested in knowing why or what address *is* being called when not providing the ip in the config or on the command line you can append the following instead in the same config file:

```
c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

In my case, running `ipython notebook` gives the following output:

```
--> 228     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    global getattr = undefined
    self._sock = <socket object, fd=6, family=2, type=1, protocol=6>
    name = 'bind'
    args = (('192.168.77.104', 8888),)
229
230 for _m in _socketmethods:
231     p = partial(meth,_m)
232     p.__name__ = _m
233     p.__doc__ = getattr(_realsocket,_m).__doc__
234     m = MethodType(p,None,_socketobject)
235     setattr(_socketobject,_m,m)
236
237 socket = SocketType = _socketobject
238
239 class _fileobject(object):
240     """Faux file object attached to a socket object."""
241
242     default_bufsize = 8192
243     name = "<socket>"

error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
```

Which only gave me a hint that it might be trying to access an invalid IP.